# How to open a div accordion on button click angular2

Tags: angular

I have an accordion as shown

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
        Collapsible Group 1</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">Text1  <button (click)="Open()">Apply</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
        Collapsible Group 2</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Text2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to open the second collapsible panel based on the button click in first panel . How can I do that in angular 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reference variables to define element used in actions:

```
<button (click)="open(panel)">Apply</button>
```

Here is your panel decorated with variable

```
<div #panel class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">Text2</div>
</div>
```

Your handler

```
open(panel) {
   panel.classList.remove("collapse");
}
```

Check this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/vadimb/p3c7k6ne/

Comment: I already have a method on click "Open()" which has functionalities on component side. I will need some code on component side only

Comment: You mean you can't change template, only class actions inside component class?

Comment: Checj your action name. Is it in correct case? In my example it in lower-case. Your example: `Open`. `#panel` ref added also

Comment: ok, it opens but i think i need to do some style fixing. It looks weird after opening

Comment: try updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vadimb/p3c7k6ne/2/ - this we do not use styles, but works with bootstrap specific classes to show panel. So may be better for UI: `panel.classList.remove("collapse");`